# Error Starting Application: Failed to forward ports

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I just started to learn Xamarin (with MvvmCross if it matters) with Visual Studio 2015 and Genymotion as emulator.

I don't know why, but after some runs, apps won't launch to emulator, and `Output Debug` will show this

```
Android application is debugging. 
Error Starting Application: Failed to forward ports.
One or more errors occurred.
```

It would just suddenly happened at x-th run. Maybe around 8~12th run. The only thing I know would make sure that the apps will launch to emulator is by restarting Visual Studio, which is quite costly in time.

Anyone knows the cause or what should I do to prevent it from happening?

====

I switched from Genymotion to Nox, doesn't happen anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem today after adding a new Android SDK to my Visual Studio 2015 in the course of searching for the solution to a different problem.  This broke my debugger for 2 days -- the app would install on the (physical) Android device but then the Debug log would say "Error Starting Application: Failed to forward ports."  And I would have to start the app manually on Android and I was not able to debug it (set breakpoints, catch exceptions, etc.).

The problem turned out to be caused by whatever combination of Android Platform Tools version 29.0.4 and my Visual Studio 2015.  After much research I discovered the problem could be fixed by reverting to an older version of the Platform Tools-- probably the newest version got installed by accident when I was in the Android SDK Manager.  You can't revert directly in the Android SDK manager -- you have to manually download the old version and replace it in its normal location in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools.  As of September 2019, Google still has older versions available, for example, I got version 28.0.0 from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.0-windows.zip .

I tested it by starting the old-version adb server manually (using the commands "adb kill-server" follwed by "adb start-server" before opening and attempting to debug my test project.  It worked, so I then installed it in the real location for platform tools, closed and reopened Visual Studio, and my debugger worked again!

Answer (score 0):

Simply restarting the emulator solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I updated Visual Studio 2017 (after trying everything else on the physical device/PC) - error went away.